# average hourly traffic over the year

Tags: rrdtool

After hours of searching the web (including SO), I am requesting advice from the community. RRD seems to be the right tool for this, but I could not get a straight answer until now.

My question is : **Is it possible to get RRD output a graph for the day, that averages data from the past year ?**

In other words, I want the "view span" to be one day long, but the "data span" to extend over the last 12 months, so that for 6pm, the value will be computed as the average value of ALL previous traffic measured at 6pm last 12 months.

Any hints, or instructions welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to create such a graph, at least in theory it would be possible using multiple DEF lines together with the SHIFT operation to create such a chart ...  you would have to use a program to create the necessary command line though